# Find n-th derivative of the function satisfying differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

Assume that $\,\frac{dx}{dt}=(x-a(t))(x-b(t)).$
I want to find a pattern for $x^{(n)}$ by generating subsequently $x^{(2)}, x^{(3)}....\,$
For example
$$x''=(x-a(t))(x-b(t))^2+(x-a(t))^2(x-b(t))-a'(t)(x-b(t))-b'(t)(x-a(t)).$$
But the formulas for higher order derivatives are much more complicated.
Can *Mathematica* help me with this?

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 2):

In the form given in the question (just plain `x`):

```
Block[{x, t, n = 2},
 x /: Dt[x] = (x - a[t]) (x - b[t]);
 t /: Dt[t] = 1;
 Nest[Dt, x, n]
 ]
(*
  (x - b[t]) ((x - a[t]) (x - b[t]) - a'[t]) +
   (x - a[t]) ((x - a[t]) (x - b[t]) - b'[t])
*)
```

In a more traditional form (with `x[t]`):

```
Block[{x, t, n = 2},
 x /: Derivative[1][x] = Function[t, (x[t] - a[t]) (x[t] - b[t])];
 Nest[D[#, t] &, x[t], n]
 ]
(*
  (-b[t] + x[t]) ((-a[t] + x[t]) (-b[t] + x[t]) - a'[t]) +
   (-a[t] + x[t]) ((-a[t] + x[t]) (-b[t] + x[t]) - b'[t])
*)
```

A more general function for the reduction, according to an ODE, of an expression involving derivatives of `x`.

```
ClearAll[reduceD];
reduceD[expr_, {ode_, x_, t_}] /; Developer`SymbolQ[x] && Developer`SymbolQ[t] :=
 Module[{dorder, maxorder, rhs, rules},
  dorder = First@First@
     Internal`ProcessEquations`DifferentialOrder[ode, {t}, {x}];
  rhs = Derivative[dorder][x][t] /. First@Solve[ode, Derivative[dorder][x][t]];
  maxorder = Max@{0, Cases[{expr}, Derivative[n_][x][t] :> n, Infinity]};
  rules = NestList[
    D[First@#, t] -> (D[Last@#, t] /. Derivative[dorder][x][t] -> rhs) &, 
    x[t] -> x[t], maxorder];
  expr /. rules
  ]
```

Example:

```
ClearAll[x];
reduceD[x''[t] + x'''[t], {x'[t] == (x[t] - a[t]) (x[t] - b[t]), x, t}]
(* long output:
  (-(-b[t] + x[t]))*((a[t] - x[t])*(-b[t] + x[t]) + Derivative[1][a][t]) - (a[t] - x[t])*((-(a[t] - x[t]))*(-b[t] + x[t]) - Derivative[1][b][t]) - 2*((a[t] - x[t])*(-b[t] + x[t]) + Derivative[1][a][t])*((-(a[t] - x[t]))*(-b[t] + x[t]) - Derivative[1][b][t]) - (-b[t] + x[t])*((-b[t] + x[t])*((a[t] - x[t])*(-b[t] + x[t]) + Derivative[1][a][t]) + (a[t] - x[t])*((-(a[t] - x[t]))*(-b[t] + x[t]) - Derivative[1][b][t]) + Derivative[2][a][t]) - (a[t] - x[t])*((-(-b[t] + x[t]))*((a[t] - x[t])*(-b[t] + x[t]) + Derivative[1][a][t]) - (a[t] - x[t])*((-(a[t] - x[t]))*(-b[t] + x[t]) - Derivative[1][b][t]) - Derivative[2][b][t])   *)
```

It can be shortened in this case by substituting `A[t] == x[t] - a[t]` and `B[t] == x[t] - b[t]`:

```
% /. {a[t] -> -A[t] + x[t], b[t] -> -B[t] + x[t]} // Simplify
(*
  A[t]^3 B[t] - B[t]^2 a'[t] + A[t]^2 (B[t] + 4 B[t]^2 - b'[t]) +  2 a'[t] b'[t] -
   B[t] (a'[t] + a''[t]) + A[t] (B[t]^2 + B[t]^3 - b'[t] - 3 B[t] (a'[t] + b'[t]) - b''[t])
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code to get the first four derivatives:

```
der[f_] := D[f /. x -> x[t], t] /. {x[t] -> x, x'[t] -> d1} // Simplify;
d1 = (x - a[t]) (x - b[t]); d2 = der[d1]; d3 = der[d2]; d4 = der[d3];
```

The expression d2 is

```
(x - b[t]) ((x - a[t]) (x - b[t]) - Derivative[1][a][t]) +
(x - a[t]) ((x - a[t]) (x - b[t]) - Derivative[1][b][t])
```

The resulting output of

```
d2 == ( (x - a[t]) (x - b[t])^2 + (x - a[t])^2 (x - b[t])
      - a'[t] (x - b[t]) - b'[t] (x - a[t])) // Expand
```

is `True` which demonstrates the equality with your expression. The higher derivatives are more complicated as the number of terms increases. For example:

```
Length /@ {d2, d3, d4}
```

returns the result

```
{2, 3, 20}
```

Of course, the code can be simplified by removing the `x -> x[t]` and `x[t] -> x` and just using `x[t]` throughout instead of the bare `x`. The choice is yours.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{D[x[t], {t, 1}],D[x[t], {t, 2}],D[x[t], {t, 3}]} //. 
Derivative[k_][x][t] -> D[(x[t] - a[t]) (x[t] - b[t]), {t, k - 1}]
(*{x'[t],x''[t],x'''[t]}*)
```

to get the first three derivatives!